# PlayFramework 2.6.x: How to get dynamically named database connection in configurations?

Tags: database, scala, playframework, configuration

I'm using mysql shard db (in application.conf)
(name: shard0, shard1, ... shard9, shardN)

Expected Code:

```
@Singleton
class ProductService @Inject() () {
    def load(id Int) = {
        DBShard.getConnection(id % 10 /*num shard (dynamic database name) */) {
            implicit conn =>
        } 

    }
```

instead of:

```
@Singleton
class ProductService @Inject() (@NamedDatabase("customers") database: Database) {
    def load(id Int) = {
        database.withConnection { implicit conn =>
            ...
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ProductService @Inject()(dbapi: DBApi)  {
   dbapi.database("shard3").withConnection { conn =>
       ...
   }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.